# При Build проекта Unity, жалуется на Gradle

Tags: android, unity3d, gradle, apk, build

Я хочу создать APK файл моего проекта в Unity, но когда запускаю build, вылетают ошибки, связанные с Gradle. JDK я скачал, не знаю что делать, подскажите. Добавил скрин ошибки [image]

Comment: На вскидку можно погадать - возможно у вас в пути к вашему юнити проекту есть русские символы? если да- избавьтесь от них и попробуйте еще раз собрать. Вы предоставили только скрины заголовков ошибок, протыкайте каждую из них и предоставьте полностью то, что там написано, чтобы можно было попытаться конкретней вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, поменял путь, убрал русские символы и всё заработало

Comment: раз помогло - оформлю как ответ, отметьте его верным, пожалуйста и закроем вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в полном пути к вашему проекту присутствуют русские (или другие не ASCII) символы. Юнити с ними не любит работать. Попробуйте изменить путь к проекту и попробовать собрать проект еще раз